# Access array with list of indices

Tags: arrays, macros, common-lisp

I want to access arrays with the indices being in a list. Let's call this utility `arefl`, and it's defined as follows:

```
(arefl array '(x y z ...)) equals (aref array x y z ...)
```

My goal is to create some generic functions that operate on matrices of any size.

I have failed to implement such a thing with macros and just `aref`. The closest thing that I have is:

```
(defmacro arefl (array is)
  "Access array by a list of indices"
  `(apply #'aref (cons ,array ,is)))
```

which works, and actually it also works with `(setf (arefl array is) value)` but the compiler, at least `sbcl`, throws a warning telling me that I'm redefining `setf` for (I guess) `apply`. The warning is:

```
; in: DEFUN (SETF AREFL**)
;     (SETF (APPLY #'AREF ARRAY (REDUCE 'CONS ARGS :FROM-END T)) NEW-VALUE)
; --> LET* MULTIPLE-VALUE-BIND LET APPLY MULTIPLE-VALUE-CALL 
; ==>
;   #'(SETF AREF)
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   defining as a SETF function a name that already has a SETF macro:
;     (SETF AREF)
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
```

--

Is there a better way? I'm looking for an implementation that works well with `setf` and does not need a call to another function like `apply` nor does do any `cons`

Comment: Hmm... I didn't know before about the accessor: `ROW-MAJOR-AREF` -- I believe all or most of my needs can be implemented using it.

Comment: @jmcejuela You mean if you do all the arithmetic on the indices in advance?

Comment: Yes. I also have an implemented method doing the inverse of `array-row-major-index`

Comment: Now your warning doesn't match your code.  E.g. `arefl` vs `arefl**`. ;-)

Comment: @LarsBrinkhoff Indeed!  jmcejuela, I just tried the definition that _I_ provided in the command line SBCL, and I do not get any such warning.  1)  Please completely restart SBCL, copy and paste my code (without executing any other definitions first) and check whether you get any warnings.  2) If you _do_ get some warnings, please also show the output of `(lisp-implementation-version)`;  there could be some SBCL bug in some version (though I think that's the less probably explanation here).

Comment: Of course, I was trying new random names to avoid name collisions altogether. In any case, I tried the definitions on a new sbcl (on the command line and on slime) and I still get the same warning. As I said, I use `SBCL 1.1.11 on MacOSX`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, `define-setf-expander` is overkill for this.

```
(defun arefl (array list)
  (apply #'aref array list))
(defun (setf arefl) (x array list)
  (setf (apply #'aref array list) x))
```

See "APPLY Forms as Places": http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/05_abe.htm

Comment: Ouch! I didn't know that only the last argument to `apply` needs to be a list. However, I had tried before `(setf (apply ...))` but the compiler (at least `sbcl`) complains with `"defining as a SETF function a name that already has a SETF macro"` and I was not sure whether I was doing something wrong.

Comment: If you want more help, you should probably include the verbatim text of the warning.  I don't see that the code that Joshua and I have provided redefines anything.

Answer (score 2):

First, though I recognize that you said

> I'm looking for an implementation that works well with `setf` and does not need a call to another function like `apply` nor does do any `cons`

however, you *can* simply use `apply 'aref` here, and *you* don't need to do any `cons`ing, since only `apply`'s final argument needs to be a list.  That means that all the following are equivalent:

```
(aref array 0 1)
(apply 'aref (list array 0 1))
(apply 'aref array (list 0 1))
(apply 'aref array 0 (list 1))
(apply 'aref array 0 1 '())
```

Most importantly, if you want to avoid calling `cons`, it means that you can do

```
(apply 'aref array indices)
```

You can use `setf` with this too (although you will have to use `#'array`, and not `'array`):

```
(setf (apply #'aref array indices) new-value)
```

Since `apply` works here, you just need to make your `aref*` and `(setf aref*)` functions (to be analogous with `list*`):

```
(defun aref* (array &rest args)
  (apply 'aref array (reduce 'cons args :from-end t)))
             
(defun (setf aref*) (new-value array &rest args)
  (setf (apply #'aref array (reduce 'cons args :from-end t)) new-value))
```

The `(reduce 'cons args :from-end t)` in those is used to support [*spreadable argument list designators*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_s.htm#spreadable_argument_list_designator), which are what `apply` uses.  Using this idiom, you can pass *exactly* the same kinds of arguments to `(aref* ...)` that you could use in `(apply #'aref ...)`.  That might be a bit more complex than the use cases that you've described, but it means that rather than having to specifically describe what sorts of arguments `aref*` takes, you can simply say (like the documentation for `apply` does), that `aref*`'s args are a spreadable argument list designator, and that `aref*` applies `aref` to the args.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please see my comment to @Lars

Comment: @jmcejuela I ran these definitions through SBCL, and I'm not getting such a warning.  Can you try these, can check?  Perhaps there was a typo and you were trying to define `(setf aref)` rather than `(setf arefl)`?  Or maybe you'd already defined a `(setf arefl)` once, and were getting the warning when redefining it?  SBCL (in the REPL, at least) warns on all redefinitions, it seems.  E.g., try `(defun foo ())` and then `(defun foo ())` again.  You'll get a warning.

Comment: Nice general way to redefine setf for apply! However, I checked the name definitions and even used new names, but I still get the warning. I'm using SBCL 1.1.11 on MacOSX

Comment: @jmcejuela You shouldn't be redefining `(setf apply)`, though;  you should be defining `(setf aref*)`.

Comment: @jmcejuela I just noticed that you said "Nice general way to redefine setf for apply" — we're **_not_** redefining setf for apply!  As Lars mentioned in his answer, the standard, in [5.1.2.5 APPLY Forms as Places](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_abe.htm) says that `(setf (apply #'aref ...) ...)` _must_ be supported.  We're not redefining that;  we're just defining something else in terms of it.  If you're getting warnings or errors about defining `(setf apply)`, something in your code differs from this code which only defines `(setf aref*)`.  If so, post a transcript.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't see any difference in my code. I updated my question with the warning log